# Compress Files Directly to xpi

Tags: firefox-extensions, zip

Some unzip tools enable to extract xpi files.

I'd be glad to know if there's a program which also enables to **compress** files directly to xpi.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`xpi` is just `zip`. Just zip your files normally, and rename your `archive.zip` with the right extension, to `archive.xpi`.

Answer (score 3):

An XPI [(XPInstall)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPI) file is simply a ZIP file containing the extension files, with the install.rdf file at the root of the ZIP.

Just create `zip` file and then change its extension to `xpi`.

**Update:**

To do it directly, you will need to add a Registry entry for custom context menu item (say Compress to XPI). It will invoke a predefined .bat file which takes selected files as input and generates xpi for that.

After doing this all you need to do is, just select all files which you want to pack in xpi and from  right click menu select **Compress to XPI** and you will have your xpi file.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your help.

I meant to ask if it was possible to directly compress to xpi from the context menu. I guess I wasn't clrear enough.

Comment: @Yaron I updated my ans. Have a look it might help...
*Right now I'm on mobile, ask If you need elaborate Instructions*

Comment: It's been a while. I guess I wasn't notified of your edited reply.

I'd be grateful if you could elaborate on the .bat file.